# addSubview not working on uiscrollview

Tags: swift2

I have this code here:

```
self.statsScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
let statsScrollViewWidth:CGFloat = self.statsScrollView.frame.width
let statsScrollViewHeight:CGFloat = self.statsScrollView.frame.height

innerScrollContentOneView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, statsScrollViewWidth, statsScrollViewHeight)
innerScrollContentTwoView.frame = CGRectMake(statsScrollViewWidth, 0, statsScrollViewWidth, statsScrollViewHeight)

self.statsScrollView.addSubview(innerScrollContentOneView)
self.statsScrollView.addSubview(innerScrollContentTwoView)

self.statsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.statsScrollView.frame.width * 2, self.statsScrollView.frame.height)
self.statsScrollView.delegate = self
```

which is trying to add 2 uiviews to a uiscrollview. The scrollview has auto layout and so do the others. There are 3 IBOutlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var statsScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var innerScrollContentOneView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var innerScrollContentTwoView: UIView!
```

connected to 3 elements in storyboard. The 2 uiviews are not children of the uiscrollview but children of the uiview that holds the uiscrollview i.e.

```
--content
----uiview
----uiview
----uiscrollview
```

The problem I am facing is when I swipe the scrollview I can see it is doing something because I can see the horizontal bar show however the uiviews do not move.

Anyone know what I am missing?

Cheers!

Comment: your viewhierarchy should be like -content  --uiscrollview
---uiview
---uiview

Comment: Tried that, same issue except now my scrollview doesn't actually scroll

Comment: can you send me the demo project?